# Can we add a gradient color style in Figma's variable?

Tags: color, layers, gradient, style, figma

Is there any way that we can save our color gradients in **Figma's variables**?

- one way I know is to save the color as Style.

But I want to implement the same using the variables property. Please see the attached screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2024, we still can't have gradients in variables (I believe coz variables can have only single values at the moment. Maybe Figma don't wanna complicate the most granular elements yet.). It was discussed in this [forum question](https://forum.figma.com/t/how-can-i-add-a-gradient-as-variable-in-the-new-june-2023-update/45900) too.

For now, maybe you could try this plugin: [**Gradients with variables**](https://www.figma.com/community/file/1295349493892095561)